# Path to find files in Google Drive REST API

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to list all the files in a sub folder. I am not understanding the API reference. 
Eg Path
My path in Google Drive will be CR/CA/UP/files. 
My path in Google Drive will be CR/NA/UP/files. 
My path in Google Drive will be CR/DD/UP/files.

For the string [q list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) provide by the google document, How should I pass this ?

Here is the Q I'm using. Please Advice what I'm wrong for the Q

```
string Q = "'CR' IN parents and title = 'UP' and trashed = 'false' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'";
IList<File> _Files = GoogleDriveHelper.GetFiles(service, Q);
```

When I'm using this it is work but i dont know refer to which parent folder CA,NA or DD

```
string Q = "title = 'UP' and trashed = 'false' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'";
```

Answer (score 0):

[To list a folders contents](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list) i.e, children you need to use this HTTP request

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/folderId/children
```

To list all children of the root folder, use the alias `root` for the `folderId` value.

`q` parameter, which is a search query combining one or more search terms is used when you want to search for a particular file inside a folder.

Comment: string Q = " mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.file' and root='NA'  and trashed = false  and title ='xxx' ";